# Função Screenshot no android

Tags: java, android, bitmap

Estou colocando a função de screenshot no calendário, porém a foto não está saindo como deveria.

[image: Esta saindo assim]

Mas usando a função nativa do android sai correto

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue trecho do código:

```
View v1 = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ScrollcalendarView);

            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

            ScrollView z = (ScrollView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ScrollcalendarView);
            int totalHeight = z.getChildAt(0).getHeight();
            int totalWidth = z.getChildAt(0).getWidth();
            v1.layout(0, 0, totalWidth, totalHeight);

            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

            File imageFile = new File(mPath);

            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            int quality = 100;
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();

            openScreenshot(imageFile);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // Several error may come out with file handling or OOM
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Alguém tem ideia do que pode ser?

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido!

Alterei a linha:

```
new float[]{0, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0}, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
```

Para:

```
new float[]{0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f}, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
```

Ficando assim:

```
private static Drawable generateSemiCircleDrawable(final int color1, final int color2) {

        ShapeDrawable drawable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
        drawable.setShaderFactory(new ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory() {
            @Override
            public Shader resize(int width, int height) {
                return new LinearGradient(0, 0, width, height,
                        new int[]{color1, color1, color2, color2},
                        new float[]{0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f}, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
            }
        });
        return drawable;
    }
```

E depois de pronto ficou assim.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Problema resolvido! em parte.
Estava usando:

```
view.setBackgroundDrawable(generateCircleDrawable(color));
```

e mudei para:

```
view.setSelectionDrawable(generateCircleDrawable(color));
```

Mas quando de trata de duas cores exemplo:

```
view.setSelectionDrawable(generateSemiCircleDrawable(color1, color2));
```

Só aparece a uma cor como pode ser visto no post.

https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview/issues/263

O estranho é que só acontece com o código no App, usando o screenshot nativo funciona bem.

Ainda aguardo sugestões